# Mapnik not generating tiles for tilecache

Tags: openlayers-2, mapnik, tilecache

Imported data by using Osm2pgsql, to get rid off all problems related to data conversion, I stored this as latlong (-l parameter). I created a stylesheet, and I tested with Python script and it was working (so both data and stylesheet should be fine).

Here comes problem... when I tried to use it with OpenLayers, I got my basic layer covered by pinkish "image not found" tile, but when I try to access tile by calling cgi script "http://localhost/tc/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/osm/5/31/26.png" I have a nicely generated tile.

Does any one have idea what I'm doing wrong?

files:

osm.xml

```
<Map background-color="#00000000" srs="+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84">
  <Style name="roadStyle">
    <Rule>
      <LineSymbolizer stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="100" />
    </Rule>
  </Style>
  <Layer name="roads" srs="+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84">
    <StyleName>roadStyle</StyleName>
      <Datasource>
       <Parameter name="table">
       (select way,highway from planet_osm_line where highway in ('motorway','motorway_link','trunk','trunk_link','primary','primary_link','secondary','secondary_link','tertiary','tertiary_link','residential','unclassified') order by z_order) as roads
       </Parameter>
      <Parameter name="type">postgis</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="user">www-data</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="password">gis</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="dbname">gis</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="estimate_extent">true</Parameter>
    </Datasource>
  </Layer>
</Map>
```

tilecatche.cfg

```
[cache]
type=Disk
base=/tmp/tilecache

[osm]
type=Mapnik
mapfile=/var/www/tc/osm/osm.xml
extension=png

[basic]
type=WMS
url=http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0
extension=png
```

Definition of my layers:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',
      {
        numZoomLevels: 12,
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
      });    
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "VMap0", 
        "tilecache.cgi?", {layers: 'basic', format: 'image/png' } );
var tms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "osm","tilecache/tilecache.cgi?",
      { layers:'osm',  format: 'image/png'},{ isBaseLayer: false}  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Not enough reputation so can't add a comment.

There can be multiple reasons behind it,

Firstly, did you check the server logs? Apache for instance. Might be an issue with the permissions.

Also, I am not much aware of TileCache have been using ModTile and Renderd (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mod_tile) so not aware of the logging of TileCache. Can you check tilecache logs?

Also, make sure you have configured your server (Apache in my case) properly with TileCache

Hope that helps.